# LaTeX: insert text below Table of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I am writing my PhD thesis wth LaTeX. I would like to insert few lines of text between the title "Table of figures" and the list of figures, see below: 
Table of Figures
#I would like to add text here# 
Figure 1......2 
Figure 2......3 
Figure 3......5 \

I am using the following command to insert the Table of Figures :

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
```

Thank you in adavance for your help,
Martin

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the standard `book` class and the `tocloft` package (see p. 7 of the package documentation).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
  \renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\\[\baselineskip] \lipsum[11]}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\chapter{Chapter one}
\chapter{Chapter two}

\begin{figure}
The figure here
  \caption{A caption here}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]